# Select items like records from a column in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table (foo) with a large number of several records and I only want to select those that are like one of the records in a field in another table (foo2)

If I do a SELECT query with an inner join

```
SELECT pst_qty AS [QTY]
  ,[MFGPN]
  ,[mfg_name] AS [MANUFACTURER]
  ,description
  ,sup_id
  FROM [foo]
  INNER JOIN [foo2]
  ON [foo].[MFGPN] = [foo2].TestString
```

afaik I would only get records where foo.field1=foo2.field1.   I can't seem to use ON foo.field1 LIKE foo2.field2 to select records like the fields in foo2.  How would I go about selecting the records that are like the records from a column in a different table?

Comment: Could you elaborate, e.g can you list columns of your foo2 tables?

Answer (score 17):

Have you tried something like

```
SELECT pst_qty AS [QTY] 
  ,[MFGPN] 
  ,[mfg_name] AS [MANUFACTURER] 
  ,description 
  ,sup_id 
  FROM [foo] 
  INNER JOIN [foo2] 
  ON [foo].[MFGPN] LIKE '%' + [foo2].TestString + '%'
```

Comment: Awesome answer !

Answer (score 3):

how about,

```
SELECT DISTINCT
            F.[pst_qty] [QTY],
            F.[MFGPN], 
            F.[mfg_name] [MANUFACTURER], 
            F.[description], 
            F.[sup_id] 
    FROM
            [foo] F 
        CROSS JOIN
            [foo2] F2
    WHERE
             CHARINDEX(F2.[MFGPN], F.[TestString]) > 0;
```

Note, this will work if the strings contain the the `'%'` wildcard character.

Comment: Yup. All other answers are subject to wildcard injection (if there is such a thing).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT pst_qty AS [QTY]
.
.
.
  FROM [foo]
       where [foo].[MFGPN] LIKE '%123%'
             or [foo].[MFGPN] LIKE '%123%'
             or [foo].[MFGPN] LIKE '%123%'
```

will  work but will require a full table scan because any index on that column will be ignored. So instead of it, following can be tried.

```
SELECT pst_qty AS [QTY]
.
.
.
  FROM [foo]
  INNER JOIN [foo2]
        ON [foo].[MFGPN] LIKE '%' + [foo2].TestString + '%'
```

Comment: With your second suggestion, an index would also be ignored. There's probably no way to enable index usage on a column that is tested with `LIKE '%something%'`.

Comment: Yes Andriy, you are perhaps right for my 2nd suggestion. I just checked it in the execution flow. But atleast it gives the answer to the query posted by user1542296   :)

Comment: @AndriyM expressions with leading wildcard can't benefit from an index. The performance will be terrible. If performance is a problem investigate a Full Text Index