# SQL Query in which the WHERE clause uses LIKE on all data from a column in another table

Tags: sql-server

Azure SQL Server 2017:

We have a table called `dbo.keywords` with one column, called `keywords`.  This column consists of ~10,000 `varchar(50)` entries.

We have another table called `dbo.articles`.  Both tables are in the same database.

The query we are trying to create would be such:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.articles
WHERE TextValue LIKE 
(**any of the 10,000 values of the keywords column in the dbo.keywords table**).
```

The part in the parentheses above is the part that I am unclear on accomplishing.  If not for the `LIKE` part, I suppose I could use a `SELECT` subquery, but the `LIKE` piece is what's throwing me.

Comment: What is it about `LIKE` you don't understand? Have you had a look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), which does explain how to use wildcards? If you don't understand how a function or operator works in SQL Server, the documentation should be one of your first ports of call. The documentation has been vastly improved over the last few years (in my view) and is also now able to be editted via the community on GitHub; making improvements and corrections far more common and accurate,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select items like records from a column in another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11642544/select-items-like-records-from-a-column-in-another-table)

Comment: Are you looking for this query? `SELECT * FROM dbo.articles [AR]
INNER JOIN dbo.keywords [KW]
ON [AR].TextValue LIKE '%' + [KW].keywords + '%';`

Comment: @Arulkumar sounds like an answer instead of a comment

Comment: though would be an incorrect answer. Probably wanted `ON` not `WHERE`

Comment: Not so sure on that @MartinSmith. I think `EXISTS` is going to be a better candidate here.

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks, I have corrected

Comment: I'm just talking about the invalid syntax in the above comment - though it has now been corrected.

Comment: @Lamak Yes, I have posted as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that this will be the more "perfomant" option (I use quotes, as using `LIKE` with a leading wildcard will make the query non-SARGable):

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.articles a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM dbo.keywords k
              WHERE a.TextValue LIKE '%' + k.keyword + '%');
```

This will avoid duplicate rows, and a costly `DISTINCT`; as I suspect that `TextValue` could have some lengthy values.

Comment: This is the one.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by using `JOIN` with `LIKE`.

Could you please try the query below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.articles [AR] 
INNER JOIN dbo.keywords [KW] ON [AR].TextValue LIKE '%' + [KW].keywords + '%';
```

Comment: This is almost the same as @Larnu answer, but since they posted first, I marked theirs as the answer.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to join the tables, and use the LIKE clause in the join condition:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.* FROM dbo.articles a
JOIN dbo.keywords k ON a.TextValue LIKE '%' + k.keywords + '%';
```